# What is the effect called when one looks at a bright light, and the image "burns" into one's eyes?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I glance at the sun, or a bare light bulb, I find that when I blink, or move my eyes, a superimposed image of the bright object appears wherever I look.  What is this called?

Comment: Compare *phosphene*, which is the same kind of image only not produced by light.

Comment: It also happens with sustained exposure to bright colors; however the after image is always the exact opposite on the color wheel, and of equal intensity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An after-image.

Oxford English Dictionary:

"The impression retained by the retina of the eye, or by any other organ of sense, of a vivid sensation, after the external cause has been removed."

Comment: I was going to say this, but the rescources that I used refered to after-image as mainly an optical illusion, not the condition of being exposed to a bright light.

Comment: @Colin: Does this definition include sounds impressed on the ear?

Comment: @drm65: why are you asking me? Your interpretation of the OED is as valid as mine.

Comment: @colin: Now that is a compliment!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_fatigue

Answer (score 1):

[Flash blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_blindness)

Comment: Though I think flash blindness means that your entire vision is impaired; this isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: I would say that my vision is impared if I have a giant round ball of light where my retina's got over exposed, lol.

Comment: The point was "entire" - not "impaired".  Flash blindness appears to imply that the _whole_ vision is affected, not just a part.

Answer (score 0):

You used to get this with plasma televisions and it was called ***burn-in***. Perhaps ***visual burn-in*** applies?

Comment: It sounds a little contrived or vernacular, but I suppose it might work somewhere.

Comment: No, *visual burn* does exist, but is something different.  Sometimes called 'navigator's eyeball', it refers to a condition where constantly looking at a bright light, (such as the sun through a sextant) has left a patch of the eyeball permanently impaired.